# How can I do a geospatial query in mongo db with a timestamp filter in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am doing a MongoDB Geospatial Query with Java;

```
 FindIterable<Document> result = collection.find(
            Filters.near("gps_location", currentLoc, 1000.0, 0.0));
```

Now I want to add a timestamp filter like

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(1585906034);
    query.put("timestamp", new BasicDBObject("$gte", timestamp));
```

How can I add the timestamp filter to the above geospatial query?

Answer (score 0):

check the [Spring data mongodb](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/mongodb.adoc) for more example, 
Using `Criteria` and `Query`, I write some template code for you, you could try

```java
Query orQuery = new Query();
 Criteria orCriteria = new Criteria();
 List<Criteria> orExpression =  new ArrayList<>();
   // multiple condition in or
   Criteria location = Criteria.and("location").near(point).maxDistance(0.01)
   orExpression.add(location);
   Criteria ts = Criteria.and("timestamp").gte(1585906034);
   orExpression.add(ts);
// build final criteria 
 orQuery.addCriteria(orCriteria.orOperator(orExpression.toArray(new Criteria[orExpression.size()])));
 List<Document> documents = mongoOperations.find(orQuery, Document.class);
```

I hope it's work for you